# Nested If And Vlookup

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have created a userform in VBA - which enters data into a table in the same workbook.

Here is what I would like to happen:

Textbox 5 will be disabled in my userform, but it should become enabled (and mandatory), if three conditions are met:

1)  The value in Textbox 1 and Textbox 2 can be found in a row in my sourcetable (in the same worksheet)

2)  The value in Textbox 3 is "0"

3) The value in Textbox 4 is "0"

I have a formula working which does the above in Excel but I'm not sure how to translate this into VBA.

Here is the formula:

=IF(AND(VLOOKUP(H5,C5:D12,2,FALSE)=I5,F5="0",G5="0"),"textbox5 becomes active and mandatory","textbox5 remains disabled"

So to translate this formula into my UserForm:

H5 would be the value in TextBox1,

C5:C12 is my lookuprange -> columns D and E in my Source Table

2 = Column E which holds the values for TextBox 2

I5 = the current value in TextBox 2

F5 = Value in Textbox 3 (needs to be 0)

G5 = Value in Textbox 4 (needs to be 0)

I hope that my description is clear, and I would really appreciate any help that I can get.

Thanks,

Comment: You can use `Application.Vlookup(TextBox1.Value, workSheetRef.Range("C5:D12"), 2, False)` and compare the return value against Textbox2

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for your advice.  This doesn't take into account that the values in Textbox 3 and Textbox 4 must be "0". Also, if these conditions are met - I'd like to understand how to make TextBox 5 become active

Comment: Generally here people post the code they've written and ask for help on how to fix a problem they're having with it.  If you just post a list of requirements then answers tend to be less common.  *Try something*, then post back with your code if you run into problems.